# Android listview how to make imageview (list item ) visible at specific position in the listview?

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I'm facing a problem that I have a listview contains text and imageview, I want to make the imageview appear on the even positions only, how to make it?

[That's what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg0ZN.png)

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView=inflater.inflate(id,null);

    }
    sora item=items.get(position);
    TextView tv_id= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sora_id);

    //TextView tv_title= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.topic);
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    final int colorPos2 = position % colors.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
    tv_id.setTextColor(colors2[colorPos2]);
    tv_id.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    tv_id.setText(item.getSora().toString());

    final ImageView b= (ImageView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (position ==2)
            {
                b.setBackgroundColor(0xAA000000);

            }
             Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Clicked on: "+position,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                 
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `getView()`

```
final ImageView b= (ImageView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
if (position%2!=0){
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Asmaa your answer solved my problem well but i tried another solution and it worked fine for me using array of drawable images

```
private int[] p = {R.drawable.im1,R.drawable.im2};
```

and used setBackgroundResource for the specified button like this

```
int imagepos = position % p.length;

    b.setBackgroundResource(p[imagepos]);
    b.getLayoutParams().height = 65;
    b.getLayoutParams().width = 65;
```